# WPF XAML Binding

Tags: binding

I have 2 tables Main and Maintest. I am using nhibernate to pull data from database and am joining 2 tables to fetch the fields from both.Now my final object has data from both the tables. Now when I debug my app I can see that I have 2 records from Main and 5 records from Maintest. But somehow I am not able to display records from Maintest.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTaskTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Main}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTaskTemplate}" Height="200" Width="200" />

    <toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Main.Maintest}" Margin="3"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False">
        <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="#"
                                            Binding="{Binding Number}"/>
            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Airline"
                                            Binding="{Binding Code}"/>

        </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </toolkit:DataGrid>
</StackPanel>

NHibernate Mapping:
<class name="Main" lazy="false">
        <id name="ID" type="Int32">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
<set name="Maintest" inverse="true">
            <key column="Ticket" on-delete="cascade" />
            <one-to-many class="Segment" />
        </set>
```

....
 I able to display listbox record but not toolkit records. Although I can see that for each Main record my object does have 3 or more records in Maintest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something doesn't add up...

ListBox.ItemsSource takes an IEnumerable of some kind - which means the property Main must be some kind of IEnumerable?

So, if what you're looking for is a Master-Detail kind of view - you need to change the XAML for the two controls like this - everything else should be fine:

```
<ListBox Name="Main" .../>
<toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Maintest,ElementName=Main}" .../>
```

This will make the DataGrid bind to the MainTest property of whatever obejct is selected in the ListBox.

Look to [Bea Costa](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/) if you really need to get spiffy with Master-Detail scenarios.

Hope this helps!